# NSPredicate is not filtering the results of a fetch request

Tags: core-data, nsstring, nspredicate

OK.  This one has me beat.

The CoreData graph matches the code you see below.

I want to filter Entities by the inherited UUID.  I am creating a predicate and a fetch request using the following code:

```
NSString *aUUID = [anObjectDescription objectForKey:@"UUID"];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:className 
                                              inManagedObjectContext:theContext];
    //see if the entity already exists
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSLog(@"blah the uuid is %@",aUUID);
    NSLog(@"Length: %d String:[%@]", [aUUID length], aUUID);
    NSPredicate *fetchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"uuid LIKE %@",aUUID];
    //NSPredicate *fetchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"nonExisting==7"];

    NSLog(@"predicate is: %@",fetchPredicate);
    [request setPredicate:fetchPredicate];
    NSError *aFetchError = nil;
    NSMutableArray *foundEntities = [[theContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&aFetchError] mutableCopy];
    //if the entity already exists then ignore the create message.
    NSLog(@"found %u entities error: %@",[foundEntities count],aFetchError);
    if ([foundEntities count] == 0) {
        //create
        NSLog(@"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!creating!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        NSManagedObject *anObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:className 
                                                                  inManagedObjectContext:theContext];
        Trackable *asTrackable = (Trackable*)anObject;
        asTrackable.isRemoteData = [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES];
        returnEntity = anObject;
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!found!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        returnEntity = [foundEntities objectAtIndex:0];
    }
```

Regardless of what string the predicate is created with I get all of the values in the table.  Yes I have tried "UUID LIKE %@", "UUID MATCHES %@", "UUID == %@", and a huge number of variations.  All of them work the same way.  No filtering is done.

Here is the output of the code as you see it above.  The other changes I have tried make no difference to the results you see here other than the log of what the predicate string is.  There should have been no matching results.  I have triple checked that the entity being requested here is not in the database.  It is clean except for one entity that has a different UUID.

```
2011-08-19 20:05:56.446 QC DBSync Example[28059:b603] working with a GameResult
2011-08-19 20:05:56.447 QC DBSync Example[28059:b603] blah the uuid is 1390FCDF-AFD1-4828-8CCC-0EBEBB741111
2011-08-19 20:05:56.447 QC DBSync Example[28059:b603] Length: 36 String:[1390FCDF-AFD1-4828-8CCC-0EBEBB741111]
2011-08-19 20:05:56.448 QC DBSync Example[28059:b603] predicate is: uuid LIKE "1390FCDF-AFD1-4828-8CCC-0EBEBB741111"
2011-08-19 20:05:56.449 QC DBSync Example[28059:b603] found 1 entities error: (null)
2011-08-19 20:05:56.449 QC DBSync Example[28059:b603] !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!found!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.  I've been stuck for hours.

Message was edited by yenrab on 8/19/11 at 6:39 PM

Answer (score 0):

Lee,

I always use either self.uuid or %K in -predicateWithFormat: as in:

p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"uuid", aUUID];

or

p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.uuid == %@", aUUID];

Enjoy,
Andrew

Comment: I tried both of those before posting.  Neither worked. It seems like the predicate is not being applied at all.  I even hard coded a value that should have returned nothing and I still got all items in the list.

Comment: Have you tried just fetching everything and then filtering with the predicate. IOW, get the fetch request out of the picture. NSPredicate is much more flexible on CoreData objects than it is when being used in a fetch. (This is a debugging tactic. Once you figure out what is going on, then you can try to write a working predicate for the fetch request.)